# MySQL variable/alias not usable

Tags: mysql, sql

So what I'm trying to do at the moment is to select a dataset of values depending on another autocalculated value.(Sounds pretty complicated. It isn't I think and I'm not that much into english)

My SQL code looks like this:

```
SELECT ticket.ref_id AS id, COUNT( * ) AS reports, (COUNT(*)/post.views) AS
treshold,post.views AS views
FROM ticket, post
WHERE ticket.ref_id = post.id AND (reports/post.views)
GROUP BY ref_id
ORDER BY views,reports DESC
```

The problem is, when I try to use **treshold** or **reports** in the WHERE clause the query fails and says that there is no such value in 'field list'.
I know where the problem is, it's that MySQL seems not to allow the use of 'self defined' fields in the WHERE clause but i really need this and I dont know how to fix it.
Just using **COUNT(*)** doesn't work either because it doesn't know what to count.

Can anyone help me on this problem? I think it's totally basic SQL but I'm stuck on this at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the the `HAVING` clause instead of `WHERE` for the unreferencable columns. It's less performant, but it will do the job.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

> The HAVING clause is applied nearly
>   last, just before items are sent to
>   the client, with no optimization.
>   (LIMIT is applied after HAVING.)
>
> A HAVING clause can refer to any
>   column or alias named in a select_expr
>   in the SELECT list or in outer
>   subqueries, and to aggregate functions

Comment: thank you :) I knew it all along that this problem was simpler as i made it